# Como pegar a primeira linha de tabela estrangeira com entity framework core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Tenho uma tabela de imóveis e Fotos imóveis, com os respectivos modelos:

Imóveis

```
[Key]
public int ImovelId { get; set; }
public int? CategoriaId { get; set; }
public string Endereco { get; set; }
public string Numero { get; set; }
```

ImoveisFotos

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ImovelId { get; set; }
public string Foto { get; set; }
```

No Controller tenho esse código:

```
IList<Imoveis> imoveisLista = new List<Imoveis>();
var imoveis = _context.Imoveis
                        .Where(i => i.LocacaoVenda == "L")
                        .Where(i => i.Bairro == bairro)
                        .Where(i => i.VisivelAluguel == 1)
                        .ToList();

                foreach (var item in imoveis)
                {
                    imoveisLista.Add(item);
                    var foto = _context.ImoveisFotos
                        .Where(x => x.ImovelId == item.ImovelId)
                        .Select(x => x.Foto).Count();
                    if (foto == 0)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Foto = "img_padrao.jpg";
                    }
                    else if(foto >= 1)
                    {
                        ViewBag.Foto = _context.ImoveisFotos
                        .Where(x => x.ImovelId == item.ImovelId)
                        .Select(x => x.Foto).First();
                    }
                }
                ViewData["ListaImoveis"] = imoveisLista;
```

E na View

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ListaImoveis"] as IList<Imoveis>)
                    {
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="card p-1 mb-2 bg-light">
                                    <h5 class="card-header text-left text-dark font-weight-bold">
                                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker text-dark"></i>

                                        <span>@item.Bairro</span>
                                        -
                                        <span>@item.Endereco</span>,
                                        <span>@item.Numero</span>
                                        -
                                        <span>@item.Complemento</span>
                                    </h5>

                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-5 text-center">

                                                <a href="detalhes?id=57">

                                                        <img class="img-fluid cover" src="https://230.112.09.34/content/uploads/imoveis/fotos/@ViewBag.Foto" />
```

A lista de imóveis vem direito, mas toda a lista repete a mesma foto, ao invés da sua tabela primaria. Meu objetivo era pegar a primeira foto de cada imóvel e exibir. Abaixo como fica:

[image: A mesma foto está sendo usada na lista de imóveis]

Como resolver isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está setando uma única referência na ViewBag (Viewbag.Foto) a cada iteração no laço foreach, por isso todos os registros ficam com a mesma imagem, pois sempre substitui a foto a cada passo.

Minha sugestão é criar uma ViewModel que receba todos os dados que quer apresentar na view:

```
public class ImoveisViewModel
{
    public int ImovelId { get; set; }
    public int? CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
}

List<ImoveisViewModel> listaImoveis = new List<ImoveisViewModel>();
```

No foreach crie um novo objeto ImoveisViewModel e no lugar de setar a ViewBag adicione na listaImoveis:

```
foreach (var item in imoveis)
            {
                var imovel = new ImoveisViewModel() {
                   ImovelId = item.ImovelId,
                   CategoriaId = item.CategoriaId,
                   Endereco = item.Endereco,
                   Numero = item.Numero
                };
                var foto = _context.ImoveisFotos
                    .Where(x => x.ImovelId == item.ImovelId)
                    .Select(x => x.Foto).Count();
                if (foto == 0)
                {
                    imovel.Foto = "img_padrao.jpg";
                }
                else if(foto >= 1)
                {
                    imovel.Foto = _context.ImoveisFotos
                    .Where(x => x.ImovelId == item.ImovelId)
                    .Select(x => x.Foto).First();
                }
                listaImoveis.Add(imovel);
            }
ViewData["ListaImoveis"] = listaImoveis;
```

Depois na View mudar o foreach:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["ListaImoveis"] as List<ImoveisViewModel>)
```

E depois na imagem:

```
<img class="img-fluid cover" src="https://230.112.09.34/content/uploads/imoveis/fotos/@item.Foto" />
```

Bem tem várias formas de resolver, mas o principal problema foi setar a string de foto na mesma ViewBag dentro do laço, no lugar de estar em lista.

Abraços

Comment: @MJSlasher, vlw mesmo. A chave de tudo era usar ViewModel. Depois no foreach como vc falou, usei um Count para percorrer a qtde de fotos, se retornasse nula, especificava uma string privada como a foto padrão, caso tivesse, pegava a primeira da lista com First(), e por fim jogava na propriedade Foto da ViewModel.